# Computing epsilon-closure. What does $E(n) \leftarrow \{n\};$ and $E(p)$ mean?

Tags: finite-automata, compilers

I'm currently reading "Engineering a Compiler" book. In the chapter that explanes computing epsilon-closure there is listed the following algorithm:[image]

But I couldn't understand what does $E(n)$ and $E(p)$ mean. I know that it has something to do with sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each state $n \in N$, we maintain a set of states $E(n)$. Eventually, $E(n)$ would contain all states reachable from $n$ via $\epsilon$-transitions.

You can think of $E$ as an array of sets. The notation $E(n)$ just means the value of $E$ at position $n$. So $E(p)$ is just the value of $E$ at position $p$.

Comment: It may be useful to note that this notation probably maps into concrete syntax that looks more like `E[n] := {n}`  in many programming languages